# Добавить автопрокрутку на слайдер

Tags: javascript, slider

У меня вот такой вопрос, как на этом слайдере сделать автопрокрутку?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";

  }
  for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide fade">
    <div class="number-text">1/4</div>
    <img src="img/slide1.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="">
    <div class="text">Первый слайд</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide fade">
    <div class="number-text">2/4</div>
    <img src="img/slide2.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="">
    <div class="text">Второй слайд</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide fade">
    <div class="number-text">3/4</div>
    <img src="img/slide3.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="">
    <div class="text">Третий слайд</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide fade">
    <div class="number-text">4/4</div>
    <img src="img/slide4.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="">
    <div class="text">Четвертый слайд</div>
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">
    <img src="img/arrow-left.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">
    <img src="img/arrow-right.png" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
<br>
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <span class="dot active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: А можете загрузить картинки сюда (на этот сайт) и добавить в ваш слайдер? Так будет лучше и наглядней смотреться в запускаемом коде.

Comment: а как их сюда загрузить? просто я буквально со вчера на этом сайте, пока что не со всем разобрался, как тут что работает

Comment: Есть такая кнопочка в редакторе "Загрузить изображение". Выбираете или с компьютера или url. Затем снизу будет ссылка. Так вот берёте и используете в `src` ссылки вместо `img/slide1.jpg` и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил `setInterval`: все работает

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";

  }
  for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
var i = 1;
  setInterval(function(){
  currentSlide(i)
  i++;
  if(i == 5)
  {
   i = 1;
  }
},2000)
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide fade">
    <div class="number-text">1/4</div>
    <img src="img/slide1.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="">
    <div class="text">Первый слайд</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide fade">
    <div class="number-text">2/4</div>
    <img src="img/slide2.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="">
    <div class="text">Второй слайд</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide fade">
    <div class="number-text">3/4</div>
    <img src="img/slide3.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="">
    <div class="text">Третий слайд</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide fade">
    <div class="number-text">4/4</div>
    <img src="img/slide4.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="">
    <div class="text">Четвертый слайд</div>
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">
    <img src="img/arrow-left.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">
    <img src="img/arrow-right.png" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
<br>
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <span class="dot active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, я всё не мог понять куда же именно setInterval ставить

Comment: можете только пометить галочкой ответ, чтоб другим было видно. спасибо

Comment: Наконец-то нашёл! Спасибо вам **огромное**)